# matching values in cells to Named ranges - vba

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

I am using VBA to try to see if values in cells from one workbook match the named ranges from another workbook and if they do match then copy paste values from another column in those named ranges. I know they will match. the purpose is just to copy the values over into their designated named range.

The problem is in this line:

```
If rng = ws2.Range("NamedRange") Then
```

Here is my code below:

```
Sub Button4_Click()

Dim strFileName As String
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim RangeName As String
Dim CellName As String


''Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
''Set ws2 = wb2.Sheet("Output")
''ws2.Range("D1:D12").Copy

''Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

strFileName = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop") & "\BAC GVP - Template_Update_121917.xlsm"

If Dir(strFileName) <> vbNullString Then
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
Else
MsgBox "Sorry, the file does not exist on your Desktop at this time, please drop a copy to your Desktop from server!"
End If

''Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
''Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Output")
''Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("RVP Local GAAP")

''ws2.Range("D4:D12").Copy
''ws1.Range("G13:G21").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

  ''RangeName = "myData"
  ''CellName = "G11:G83"

  ''Set cell = Worksheets("RVP Local GAAP").Range(CellName)
  ''ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=RangeName, RefersTo:=cell

  ''RangeName = "NamedRange"
  ''CellName = "C4:C12"


Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Output")
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("RVP Local GAAP")

For Each rng In ws1.Range("CurrentTaxPerLocalGAAPProvision")
    If rng = ws2.Range("NamedRange") Then
    ws2.Range("ReportBalance").Copy
    ws1.Range("CurrentTaxPerLocalGAAPProvision").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    MsgBox "Values Copied Successfully"
End If
Next rng
MsgBox "Both Ranges do not have the same data"
End Sub
```

See image below - Cell G29 is called "GVP_Donations_CurrentTaxPerLocalGAAPProvision"... so for this example I would want $4,313 to appear in the cell G29

CurrentTaxPerLocalGAAPProvision:

[image: CurrentTaxPerLocalGAAPProvision]

Range ("NameRange"):

[image: Range ("NameRange")]

Comment: What is the address of the named range called `NamedRange`?  Is it a single cell, or multiple cells?  (If multiple cells, you can't compare a single value to an array.)

Comment: The named ranges have different names, so multiple cells with different named ranges. For example) cell A - named range "A" cell b named range = "B." and then I have a table with values A, B, etc. and I want to check if those values in the table match the names of the named ranges, (if that makes sense). Also the values in the table the entire column I've named it "NamedRange"

Comment: ' the entire column I've named it "NamedRange" ' - in that case `rng = ws2.Range("NamedRange")` will not work - VBA does not support comparing a scalar to a vector.  What are you trying to do in that statement?  Are you trying to see whether the entire column has the same value as `rng.Value`, or are you trying to see whether `rng.Value` exists somewhere within the column?

Comment: I'm trying to compare if the cell values in a named range called ("NamedRange") are used as named ranges in multiple cells in a rng called (CurrentTaxPerLocalGAAPProvision). So there are multiple cells and I created named ranges for all the cells now I'm trying to compare the cell's values in ("NamedRange") to see if those values exist as a named range in the (CurrentTaxPerLocalGAAPProvison) name range. Sorry I'm horrible at explaining and very new to VBA.

Comment: So for each value in `CurrentTaxPerLocalGAAPProvision` range you want to see if it exists as a value anywhere within the `NamedRange` range and, if **any** of those values from the `CurrentTaxPerLocalGAAPProvision` range does match, you want to replace the entire `CurrentTaxPerLocalGAAPProvision` range with the values taken from the `ReportBalance` range.

Comment: yes however, when you say value -  I'm comparing the values from NamedRange to the names of the cells (aka named ranges) in CurrentTaxPerLocalGAAPProvision. So all the cells in the range CurrentTaxPerLocalGAAPProvisions have a unique named range in each cell.

Comment: OK - gradually getting a better understanding - for each value in the "NamedRange" range you want to look to see if there is an entry in the workbook's `Names` which has a `Name` equal to the value and which has a `RefersTo` that intersects with (or is wholly within?) the "CurrentTaxPerLocalGAAPProvision" range and, if you find such a value, you want to replace all the values in the "CurrentTaxPerLocalGAAPProvision" range.

Comment: Yes I think that's correct... also I added two images above, with an example I think that will help better explain it.

Comment: Ohhh - So you don't want to replace the whole range at all - all you are wanting to do is something like `For Each rng In ws1.Range("NamedRange") : ws2.Range(rng.Value).Value = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value : Next`

Comment: Oops - my last comment had `ws1` and `ws2` reversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line saying

```
If rng = ws2.Range("NamedRange") Then
```

is crashing out due to the attempt to compare the value of `rng` (e.g. `""` when `rng` is referring to the cell G29) with an array of values (the values in "NamedRange").  VBA cannot handle the comparison of a scalar to a vector.  But it isn't what you are wanting to do anyway.

---

I believe that, to do what it seems you are trying to do, you can replace your loop with:

```
'Loop through all the values in NamedRange
For Each rng In ws2.Range("NamedRange")
    'Transfer the value from the next column to the appropriate range in the
    'destination sheet
    ws1.Range(rng.Value).Value = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
Next
MsgBox "Values Copied Successfully"
```

---

If only **some** of the values in "NamedRange" should be copied, then you may need to include a bit of testing to see whether the ranges are in the correct target area:

```
Dim dstRng As Range
'Loop through all the values in NamedRange
For Each rng In ws2.Range("NamedRange")
    Set dstRng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set dstRng = ws1.Range(rng.Value)
    On Error GoTo 0
    'Check that the range exists in destination sheet
    If Not dstRng Is Nothing Then
        'Check that the range exists in the appropriate area
        If Not Intersect(dstRng, ws1.Range("CurrentTaxPerLocalGAAPProvision")) Is Nothing Then
           'Transfer the value from the next column to the appropriate range in the
           'destination sheet
           dstRng.Value = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    End If
Next
MsgBox "Values Copied Successfully"
```

Comment: Amazing! thanks loads.. and thanks for bearing with me on this.

Comment: Can I ask one more question? if I wanted to add a message box somewhere to let the user know that values copied over successfully, where can I do that? I've tried putting it after dstRng.Value = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value.. however the message box keeping appearing more than once.

Comment: @Clarisa Just put it after the `Next` statement.  (I was thinking your original code had a message there but, re-looking at the question code, the placement of those messages didn't make much sense.  After the `Next`, you are finished copying, so that is a good place to say "I'm finished - now you can do something".)  Have added it into the answer's code.

Comment: Can I ask another question related to this? not sure if I should just write out a new question but because you helped me so well before wanted to reach out directly.. where can I add a message box if the range does not exist in the destination sheet then add a message box that says "xyz failed, 3 amounts did not carry over, or something like that? just so I know if it ever fails and on which ones? I'm guessing some sort of try catch??.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would probably be best to raise a new question.  (But, if you are using the last block of code from my answer, I think all you need is `Else` statements on the two `If`s and in both of the `Else` blocks display an appropriate message - e.g. `MsgBox rng.Value & " not in 'RVP Local GAAP' sheet"` and `MsgBox rng.Value & " not in relevant section of 'RVP Local GAAP' sheet"`.)